# Live-Patch Internal Error persisting

Tags: canonical-livepatch

I see this error reminding me something wrong with Live-Patch --> [Image here & not posted for having less reputation points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NitNT.png)

I added my token and enabled it. After that I did,

```
sudo canonical-livepatch refresh
```

For some days I saw no error and okay sign on the above Live-Patch notifier was restored.

This is the screenshot I took back then,

[Image here & not posted for having less reputation points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPXhA.png)

Now for last few day --- I am again seeing the same error.

So I tried refreshing it again,

```
sudo canonical-livepatch refresh
```

But now I see the output as,

```
checking for patches
nothing to apply
kernel: 5.4.0-37.41-generic
patch state: ✗ the application caused a crash last time it was applied, check system logs with `journalctl -f -t canonical-livepatch`
patch version: 69.1
```

I tried,

```
journalctl -f -t canonical-livepatch
```

I see the output as,

```
-- Logs begin at Thu 2020-07-30 16:25:52 IST. --
Aug 04 22:45:39 g560 canonical-livepatch[1094]: error in livepatch check state: check-failed
Aug 04 22:45:39 g560 canonical-livepatch[1094]: System contains non-livepatch tainted modules.
Aug 04 22:45:39 g560 canonical-livepatch[1094]: Module may have caused kernel crash! Not inserting module.
Aug 04 22:45:39 g560 canonical-livepatch[1094]: To override this warning, remove /var/snap/canonical-livepatch/common/locks/livepatch_Ubuntu_5_4_0_37_41_generic_69_69.1
Aug 04 22:45:39 g560 canonical-livepatch[1094]: during refresh: multiple failures
Aug 04 22:45:39 g560 canonical-livepatch[1094]: during refresh: cannot check: apply-failed
Aug 04 22:45:39 g560 canonical-livepatch[1094]: during refresh: cannot apply patches: lock file "/var/snap/canonical-livepatch/common/locks/livepatch_Ubuntu_5_4_0_37_41_generic_69_69.1" already exists
Aug 04 22:45:39 g560 canonical-livepatch[1094]: error in livepatch check state: check-failed
Aug 04 22:45:39 g560 canonical-livepatch[1094]: failure when getting status: apply-failed
Aug 04 22:45:39 g560 canonical-livepatch[1094]: failure getting status after refresh: apply-failed
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Aug 04 22:45:39 g560 canonical-livepatch[1094]: To override this warning, remove /var/snap/canonical-livepatch/common/lock/livepatch_Ubuntu_5_4_0_37_41_generic_69_69.1

After remove the livepatch_Ubuntu_5_4_0_39_43_generic_69_69.1 repeat 'sudo canonical-livepatch refresh', it worked for me.